# const-correctness in void methods and lambda 'trick'

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, theory, c++14

I have a method that accepts a reference of an object as const, this method doesn't change anything of the method and the const indicates that, the thing is that this method also calls other method that is within the class and is void, doesn't accept any argument and is also virtual, meaning that the class that extends the base class can override the method BUT it needs to be const as well. Eg:

```
#include <iostream>

class Boz
{
public:
    virtual void introduce() const = 0;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void callable() const
    {
        // ...
    }

    void caller(const Boz& object) const
    {
        callable();
        object.introduce();
    }
};

class Bar : public Boz
{
public:
    void introduce() const
    {
        std::cout << "Hi." << std::endl;
    }
};

class Biz : public Foo
{
public:
    void callable() const
    {
        std::cout << "I'm being called before the introduce." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Biz biz;
    biz.caller(Bar());

    return 0;
}
```

The output would be:

```
I'm being called before the introduce.
Hi.
```

As you can see `callable` must to be const in order to be called. If I change and do this:

```
class Biz : public Foo
{
public:
    void callable()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm being called before the introduce." << std::endl;
    }
};
```

It will compile not errors are thrown but the callable method won't be called, but the virtual one as it's defined as const. It's quite obvious.

The trickiest part here:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void callable()
    {
        // ...
    }

    void caller(const Boz& object) const
    {
        auto trick = [&] () { callable(); };

        trick();

        object.introduce();
    }
};

class Biz : public Foo
{
public:
    void callable()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm being called before the introduce." << std::endl;
    }
};
```

It works and the `callable` method is called. No errors like `passing 'const ...' as 'this' argument`.

What I'm trying to do is to call `callable` without the need of being const and the reason is simple: The method doesn't change anything, he don't have access to the object that is begin passed as argument on `caller` method then we assume that he doesn't have the need to be `const` but the compiler throws an error even that way. The real problem is that `callable` is virtual and classes can extend the base class, implement their own `callable` and try to call other methods but can't if it's not `const` as well.

What I want is pretty much that, is to know how can I call the virtual method without the need of being const (the reason is pretty much that, I'm kind forcing the users that extends the class and override the `callable` method to only call `const` methods and this is not what I want) and of course understand what happens with the lambda and why it works.

Comment: Well you could just pass non-const `Boz&` to `caller`, unless you specifically want to pass rvalues to it...

Comment: By declaring the argument as const, you are promising the caller that you will not change the argument's state.  How can you respect that promise if you then pass on the argument to an unknown method that does not also make the same promise?

Comment: Lambda trick doesn't look like something that should work as it effectively discards `const` on `this`. `clang` doesn't accept this code, but `g++` does. You need `const_cast` to do something like this or, probably better idea, redesign your code so that you don't need to discard `const`.

Comment: @wakjah - That is it, I won't change anything of the method and I want to avoid that even by mistake. The only thing that is going to happen is calling methods of the object passed as argument.

Comment: @AndréCaron - `How can you respect that promise if you then pass on the argument to an unknown method that does not also make the same promise?` - The method is void, and has no arguments and is being just called, I'm not passing the object along with the calling, just calling the virtual method itself.

Comment: @zch - I didn't knew that it won't work on clang because I'm using g++. There's no way to redesign the code because there's nothing wrong as I can see. What I need is to call the virtual method before the method of the object that is passed by reference being called. How can I redesign that?

Comment: `this` is implicitly passed to methods.  You are casting away `const` via a bug.  Do an explicit `const_cast` and own the possible undefined behaviour rather than relying on a bug.

Comment: By making `Foo::caller()` const, you promise to whomever calls is that it won't change the `Foo` object. Now you want to break this promise. This is what's wrong with your design. If you don't mind `caller()` changing `Foo`, then drop `const` from it (while still taking `Boz` by const reference) - as in `void caller(const Boz& object) {...}`. If you do mind `caller()` changing `Foo`, then why do you want `callable()` to be non-const?

Comment: If the member function never changes `*this` object than it should be `const`. It's hard to say more without knowing what your are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I understand you all, but I want you guys to understand my frustration with this. I'm not saying I'm right but it's quite weird because how can a void method that has no arguments, being called inside of the method modify the object? What I'm trying to say is that the compiler would know when a method that is obvious not going to modify to be accepted. I might be missing something or don't know but how can that happen? How a void method that has no argument and is void modify or violate that promise?

Comment: The return value or the arguments is completely immaterial to whether the function changes the object.  Imagine `void callable() { ++x; }` where `x` is a member of your class.

Comment: I think your missing the fact that marking member function as `const` refers to implicit `this` parameter, rather than explicit function parameters.

Comment: It's a non-static method - it does effectively take an argument, namely `this`. It has full access to any data members of `Foo`.

Comment: I thought that `const` was the promise between the argument and the method and not the class entirely. - Then when a method accepts an object as const it means that I'm promising the object passed as argument that nothing of my class if being changed or nothing of the object passed is being changed?

Comment: In `void caller(const Boz& object) const`, there are two instances of `const`. The first one promises not to change `object`; the second one promises not to change `*this`.

Comment: `r_type f(...) const` is a promise that `object.f(...)` will not change `object` through this reference.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - Now I understand. Thank you. - But what is happening with the lambda? I really want to understand why this is working on g++. - I was studying lambdas and lambdas can capture by value and argument. If I try to capture a reference by value I got errors and I need to set the lambda as `mutable` but I can capture by reference and I assumed that this is what is happening. The lambda made a copy of the object and is calling the method inside of it instead of calling directly. Am I right?

Comment: `But what is happening with the lambda?` A compiler bug, far as I can tell. It shouldn't compile.

Comment: @zch - Thank you as well. - @IgorTandetnik - That is weird. - The last question: Shall I use `const_cast` in this case? Or it's better to avoid and try to redesign? And when exactly I can use `const_cast`?

Comment: You shouldn't use `const_cast`. You should decide already whether or not you want `Foo` constant. If you do want it constant, put `const` both on `caller` and `callable`. If you don't, then remove `const` from both. I'm talking about `const` that goes between the closing paren and the opening brace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code with the lambda definitely shouldn't compile, it's simply a GCC bug (reported as [PR 60463](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60463) and [PR 60755](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60755)) which is now fixed in the svn trunk, by http://gcc.gnu.org/r210292

If you *really* need to call a non-const member function from a const one you need to cast away the constness:

```
const_cast<Foo*>(this)->callable();
```

But this is quite risky, for at least two reasons

1. if the object was declared `const` then it is undefined behaviour e.g. `const Foo f; f.caller(boz);` is undefined behaviour.
2. you're calling a virtual function, you don't necessarily know that the derived class' override definitely doesn't modify anything. The whole point of virtual functions is that a derived class can do something different and the base class doesn't know the details.

I would change your design so that the virtual function you want to call is `const`, or the `caller` function is non-const. Anything else is dangerous.